# Can not show leader board after uploading app to google play store

Tags: android, certificate, sha1, leaderboard, app-signing

When run my app from Android studio, the leader board works well. But after uploading to Google Play Store, the leader board can not open in my game.

I searched for a month, but I did not found the correct answer.
I followed this answer: 
https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/2045

-> Delete all credentials and create new credentials with app signing SHA1 certificates, then linked app again. (I created with 3 SHA1 certificates: Android Studio SHA, App signing certificate SHA1, Upload certificate SHA1).
Now, I can log in and access to leader board. But the leader board displays the bellow message:
Hmmm, Something went wrong in Play Games.

Can someone help me?
It takes me many times for this issue.
Thank you in advance!

Can not show leader board after uploading my app to Google play store.

Answer (score 1):

Go into the Game Services section of the Developer Console.  Select Link Another app and put in the release SHA1 certificate.  If you use Firebase, also copy the release certificate to Firebase by clicking the settings icon and pasting the release SHA1.  Download the google_services JSON file to your app directory in Android Studio.  Create a new release version and upload to Developer Console.  Test the app in alpha channel.  You should be all set.